# how to convert multiple data of single column into single row and multiple column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame having 2 columns and there are multiple repetitive items in column A and their respective values in column b( which are non-repetitive).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU2LY.png)

I want to convert this data frame in the desired format as per the attached Picture-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBJsD.png)

Comment: Welcome Anuj. Next time, try to paste an example of code you have tried, preferably with some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
#Sample data:
x = [['a', 'v1'],['a', 'v2'], ['b', 'v10'],['b', 'v20'],['c', 'v10']]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['category', 'data'])
print(df)
print('------')
df2 = df.groupby('category')['data'].apply(list)
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  category data
0        a   v1
1        a   v2
2        b  v10
3        b  v20
4        c  v10
-----------
category
a      [v1, v2]
b    [v10, v20]
c         [v10]
Name: data, dtype: object
```